# Issue with separating each part of the body of my model to different animations

Tags: animation, rigging, export

So basically I'm trying to make a character for an fps game, and I'll need to blend the animations of the legs and arms in unity.

So in order to do that i made it so that the actions for the arms do not have any keys on the leg bones, and for the leg actions there's no arm keyframes.

How ever for some reason it appears that the legs and arms still affect each other and i cant blend them properly in unity because they control each other.

i dont know if i can provide any images that will help you understand the issue so ask if you require any.

Comment: Hello, maybe you need to make sure that you've removed all the arms keyframes in the legs animation and vice versa?